# Symfony security core Interface doesnt load

Tags: class, symfony, security, components, loading

A simple but silly problem is blocking me on symfony tonight...
I need to use the UserInterface class of the security component to retrieve information about the current user. However symfony tells me that this class doesn't exist. I checked "security" is well installed and the paths are good...

My code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Profile;
use App\Entity\Candidature;
use App\Form\CandidatureType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class CandidateController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/candidate", name="candidate")
     */
    public function new(Request $request, UserInterface $user): Response
    {
        // NEED TO BE CONNECTED !!
        if ($user->getUsername()) {
            // SOME CODE ...........

        } else {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('security_login');
        }
    }
}
```

[image: The error i get (screenshot)]

Error i get (quote)

> Cannot autowire argument $user of
> "App\Controller\CandidateController::new()": it references interface
> "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface" but no such
> service exists. Did you create a class that implements this interface?

Comment: If you happen to be using Symfony 5.2+ then there a new PHP attribute called [CurrentUser](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-2-controller-argument-attributes) which will allow your code to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The autowiring mechanisms only work for services and the UserInterface is not a service it’s just a contract to deal with the core security of Symfony.
If you want to get the current user you should inject the `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security` class [see documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-fetching-the-user-from-a-service)

Comment: Since they are inside of an AbstractController, a simple $this->getUser() would also work.

Comment: That’s true 

Answer (score -1):

In config/services.yml

```
services:
    App\Controller\CandidateController:
       arguments:
        $user: '@Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User'
```

-Add for $user the real class:

-You can also move this check to a service class itself, and inject this $user inside the service class.

EDIT:

Note this solution if you want to switch between different user components in the future and now.

Comment: There is no user service.  And if there was then autowiring would work fine.  Make a test project and see for yourself.

Comment: @Cerad I meant he needs to create it by himself, I know auto wiring should work fine, but I thought he needs to pass a different "user Security" component.

Comment: Well yes.  They need to pass a security service.  Which is why your answer is just plain wrong.  Plus, your code uses constructor injection which is also just plain wrong for this particular question.  Double whammy.